# Node terminal doesn't show after react native project run

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

I have a React Native project that had 0.65.3 React Native version. I updated the project from 0.65.3 to 0.73.0 and Node Terminal doesn't show while the project was running in screen after the version updating. it would show before the updating. I can't reload, etc. on terminal because of the problem. When I start the project, it says build success in the normal terminal and it looks like the picture below. The project opens but why the node screen does not open? Or if it opens, how can I see it?

[image]